# Automatic adding of p tags and br tags in editor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, editor

I want to add to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<h1>This is a heading</h1>");
document.write("<p>This is a paragraph</p>");
</script>
```

wordpress editor.I have added this in the html mode of the editor but it gets changed to

```
<p>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
document.write("
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>");
document.write("
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>");
// ]]></script>
</p>
```

I have tried inserting  between the script code but not working.
I have tried couple of plugins like raw html and inline javascripts but still its not helping.????

Answer (score 1):

have you tried with this?

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

Thanks

Comment: But removing the filter **the_content** it will effect the other editor in the different posts.I need this only for some of the posts

Comment: than you have to put a condition for that "post id lists"

Comment: But the post id may be dynamic because the client can add any javascripts in any posts

Comment: so how do you check? for which post would you like to apply this